# Open native terminal in vim

Tags: vim

To open a new file in a horizontal split I can do:

`:sp file.py`

Is there a way to open my native terminal (I'm on mac) in the same way? Something like:

`:sp terminal`?

Answer (score 1):

`:terminal` is what you want.

See `:help terminal`

Answer (score 0):

My vim mappings

```
nmap <leader>t :term<cr> " horizontal split
nmap <leader>tv :botright vertical terminal<cr> " vsplit
```